# limit of a function tends to Dirac delta function

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Let

$f_K(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\exp\{i\pi kx\}=\exp\{i\pi(K-1)x/2\}\frac{\sin(\pi Kx/2)}{\sqrt{K}\sin(\pi x/2)}$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

I want to know whether the limit of $f_K(x)$ is a Dirac delta function when $K\to\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_K(x)\,dx=\frac{2\,\pi}{\sqrt K}
$$
converges to $0$ as $K\to\infty$, so the answer is no.

Comment: Why the range of integration is set as $[-\pi,\pi]$ rather than $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: In addition, if $f_K(x)$ is scaled with a factor $2\pi/\sqrt{K}$, will the new function tend to Dirac delta when $K\to\infty$?

Comment: Also, how are the integration results obtained?

Comment: We can chose to integrate on any interval we wish. I have chosen $[-\pi,\pi]$ because the sum looks a partial sum of a Fourier series on that interval. The integrals of the terms in the sum are all $0$ except the one corresponding to $k=0$.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a function which tends to the Dirac delta function using the exponential sum mentioned above?

Comment: The Dirichlet kernel $$D_N(x)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\sum_{k=-N}^Ne^{ikx}$$ "converges" to $\delta$.